# PostgreSQL error: Connection terminated unexpectedly for long queries

Tags: node.js, postgresql, pg-promise

I'm trying to add tens of thousands of Twitter profiles to a PostgreSQL database using the function below. The Twitter part works great - I get batches of 5000 ids, push them to a master array `allFollowers`, then pause for 15 mins when the API rate limit hits (after fetching 75000 profiles) before getting the next batch of followers.

The problem is, I think, that by the time the function pauses for 15 mins, the database connection closes. When the function is done running, I get the error `Connection terminated unexpectedly`. When I run this on a Twitter account with under 75000 followers, so it doesn't have to pause, there are no problems.

I'm connecting to the database using [pg-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg-promise) with the default options. I've tried many of the suggestions in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49697082/node-postgres-connection-terminated-unexpectedly) - namely a huge `idleTimeoutMillis` value (longer than the time the function takes to run) or setting it to 0, but no luck. They all seem to perform the same as the default settings.

I also tried explicitly calling `db.connect()` before the `await addProfiles` line, but that didn't change anything either.

```js
async function getTwitterFollowers() {
    const allFollowers = []
    const targetAccount = 'TwitterDev'

    await getGroupOfFollowers(-1) // Default cursor for the Twitter API is -1

    async function getGroupOfFollowers(cursor) {
        await T.get('followers/ids', {
            screen_name: targetAccount,
            stringify_ids: true,
            cursor: cursor,
            count: 5000,
        })
            .then(async (res) => {
                const followerIds = await res.data.ids
                followerIds.map((id) => {
                    allFollowers.push(id)
                })

                // Paginate and get the next 5000 followers if the first page is full
                if (followerIds.length === 5000) {
                    await getGroupOfFollowers(res.data.next_cursor)
                }
            })
            .catch(async (err) => {
                // This is expected to fail due to Twitter rate limiting, so we pause and try again
                // This is why the queries are so long
                console.error('Trying again in 15 mins.', err.twitterReply.errors[0].message)

                // Pause for 15 mins
                await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 900000))

                // Try again
                await getGroupOfFollowers(cursor)
            })
    }

    // It could take many hours to get to this point for large Twitter accounts
    try {
        await addProfiles(
            allFollowers.map((id) => ({
                id: id,
                added: new Date(),
            }))
        )

        console.log(`Added/updated ${allFollowers.length} profiles to the database`)
    } catch (err) {
        console.error("Error adding target accounts' followers to the database.", err)
        // This is the "Error: Connection terminated unexpectedly"
    }

    return allFollowers
}
```

I'm wondering if my problem is in the database initiation options (again, of which I use all default settings because other suggested answers didn't work), or keeping the connection live another way. Would appreciate any ideas.

Comment: What does the database log file say?

Comment: @jjanes I'm using [Railway's PostgreSQL service](https://docs.railway.app/databases/postgresql) so not sure I can access a log file. Will try this same thing with a local db and get back

Comment: @jjanes update - it was just a Railway issue. It works as expected on a local database. Appreciate you trying to help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was just a [Railway](https://railway.app/) issue (the PostgreSQL host I was using). The same issue appears when using [Render](https://render.com/) and other similar platforms. Using AWS or Google Cloud works as expected.